# How to implement multiple options with cobra

Tags: go, go-cobra, cobra

I try this:
`projCmd.Flags().StringVarP(&flag, "type", "t", flag, "help")`

But, how to implement multiple options with cobra like this:
`mycli new -t one -n two`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a second line with the next option you want to add. You are not limited to use one.

Eg:

```
projCmd.Flags().StringVarP(&flag, "type", "t", flag, "help")
projCmd.Flags().StringVarP(&flag2, "some", "s", flag2, "some description")
```